# Mixture Model Distributions

Tags: gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution

I wonder, if there could be a Pareto Mixture Model, just like the Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM). How am I supposed to build a Pareto Mixture Model (PMM)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be mixture model using *any* distributions. Recall that mixture probability mass function, or probability density is

$$ f(x) = \pi_1 f_1 (x) + \pi_2 f_2 (x) + \dots + \pi_k f_k (x) $$

where $f_i$ are individual distributions and $\pi_i$ are weights such that $0 \le \pi_i \le 1$ and $\sum_i \pi_i = 1$.

I doubt there is software that will out-of-the-box implement such model for you, but you can easily estimate it's parameters using [expectation-maximalization algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm) (in fact Wikipedia uses finite mixture model as example while describing it). Here you can find [working EM code](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Em_old_faithful.gif) that can be adapted to mixture of Pareto distribution.